# UILabel with dynamic height not working for same string in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uilabel

I using below code in my application to get dynamic height for UILabel.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(231, FLT_MAX);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [labelString
                            sizeWithFont:self.verbLabel.font
                            constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                            lineBreakMode:self.verbLabel.lineBreakMode];

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = self.verbLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    self.verbLabel.frame = newFrame;
    return newFrame;
```

My labelString is What if you asked a controversial public figure? What ideas might he/she suggest?
So sometimes I'm able to show this whole string but sometimes it just cut the some text.
How can I solve this ... please help me and let me know If am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set numberOfLines to 0 to allow for any number of lines.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: Yes I have already set numbers of lines = 0 and sizeToFit for it still getting the issue.

Comment: Check with your label height?.. Just NSLog to know height. Where you set `numberOfLines`?

Answer (score 1):

i'd advise you to use the following approach instead of the `sizeWithFont:` thing:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(231, FLT_MAX);
CGSize requiredSize = [self.verbLabel sizeThatFits: maximumLabelSize];
self.verbLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, requiredSize.width, requiredSize.height);
```

This is much cleaner and will probably work better for you!

setting `self.verbLabel.numberOfLines = 0;` may be also beneficial.

[Here's](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html) a good explanation why using `sizeThatFits` is better than using `sizeWithFont`.